# plain javascript - get the value of a checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var vettore = document.getElementById(id_form).elements;


for (var i = 0; i < vettore.length; i++)
   {
    if (vettore[i].checked)
            {
            contatore++;

            valore_corrente = document.getElementById.elements[i].value;

            stringaFileSelezionati+= valore_corrente;

            stringaFileSelezionati+= '?';
            }
   }

  if (contatore == 0) 
{
alert('Error!!! No file selected!');
return false;
}
 else 
{
    alert(stringaFileSelezionati);

}
```

The error is in the line:

```
valore_corrente = document.getElementById.elements[i].value;
```

how can i get that value?

EDITED: Maybe the error is in the checkboxes creation since I got undefined:

```
                                    cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="' + 'checkbox'+" value=" + vettore_nomi_file[i] + '" id="' +i+ '" />'+vettore_nomi_file[i];
```

Comment: id's should be unique on the page. So getElementById should only ever return one element. If this isn't the case your markup is technically invalid.

Comment: u know document.getElementById needs a parameter right?

Comment: @AndréJunges right, you need to read the docs on [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

Comment: It's the ID of a form and with elements I take all it's child elements: all it's checkboxe

Answer (score 2):

You retrieve `.value` from the same object you retrieved `.checked` from:

```
valore_corrente = vettore[i].value;
```

The object is an [`HTMLInputElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#htmlinputelement) instance. The value of the checkbox is reflected in the `value` property, just like whether it's checked is reflected in the `checked` property.

Here's a complete, working example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/uVEvOrU/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/uVEvOrU/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="theform">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" checked>Uno</label>
    <br><label><input type="checkbox" value="2" checked>Due</label>
    <br><label><input type="checkbox" value="3">Tre</label>
    <br><input type="button" id="thebutton" value="Click">
  </form>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("thebutton").onclick = function() {
      var id_form = "theform";
      var vettore = document.getElementById(id_form).elements;

      var contatore = 0;
      var valore_corrente;
      var stringaFileSelezionati = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < vettore.length; i++)
      {
        if (vettore[i].checked)
        {
          contatore++;

          valore_corrente = vettore[i].value;

          stringaFileSelezionati+= valore_corrente;

          stringaFileSelezionati+= '?';
        }
      }

      if (contatore == 0) 
      {
        alert('Error!!! No file selected!');
        return false;
      }
      else 
      {
        alert(stringaFileSelezionati);

      }

    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With valore_corrente = vettore[i].value; I get error: undefinedon? (this was my first try)

Comment: @newtphp: It [works for me](http://jsbin.com/icAQoVa/1/edit) if I declare variables. Note that in your code, you're not declaring several variables, and in one case (`stringaFileSelezionati`) you're trying to *use* the value of it without having either declared it or given it a value. If you just assign to something you haven't declared, [you fall prey to *The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) and it seems to work. But if you try to *read* a value from something you haven't declared, that's a runtime error.

Comment: I did the declaration of (stringaFileSelezionati) I only forgotten to past in the code here
This is the way i got those checkboxes...maybe the error is here:
cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="' + 'checkbox'+" value=" + vettore_nomi_file[i] + '" id="' +i+ '" />'+vettore_nomi_file[i];

Comment: @newtphp: Well, I don't know what to tell you. If `vettore[i].checked` is true, `vettore[i].value` will not be `undefined`. It can be a blank string, but not `undefined`. And as you can see from the example, it *does* work.

Comment: Can this be related to the fact that If I try to see the content of the page i got error: ERR_CACHE_MISS ?

Comment: @newtphp: That seems unlikely.

Comment: I made another try. With valore_corrente = vettore[i].value; I don't get undefined i get on? If i check 2 values I got on?on? Why I got on and not the value?

Comment: @newtphp: If you're seeing `"on"`, that means you're not succeeding in setting the `value` attribute of the `input` element. The default `value` for a checkbox is `"on"` (when checked). The reason for that is your code for setting the cell's content messes up its quotes. This fixes those quotes: `cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="' + vettore_nomi_file[i] + '" id="' +i+ '" />'+vettore_nomi_file[i];` But note that using an `id` value starting with a digit will lead to trouble with CSS selectors (it's fine otherwise).

Comment: I LOVE YOU THAT WAS THE ERROR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I don't need the ID so I think I will remove it to avoid problems! Thanks very much for you time! Can you give me an advice about that damed code line? How can i prevent that kind of errors? This isn't the first time:
cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="' + vettore_nomi_file[i] + '" id="' +i+ '" />'+vettore_nomi_file[i];

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work:

```
valore_corrente = vettore[i].value;
```